# Handlebars registerPartial() is not working

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, templating-engine

Here is my code on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chhantyal/pkQLw/)

Error- Uncaught Error: The partial social could not be found

PS. I have included all the libs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was using partial before this:

```
$('ul').append(template(data));
```